# Can't get text from link using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am not able to get link text using selenium. I want the text from the link ,ie 842 in the code below. I tried getting by class and xpath. But the text returned is empty string. Please help

[image: See image]

Python Code:

```
elems = wd.find_elements_by_class_name("gsc_g_al")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
elems=wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/a[18]/span')
    for elem in elems:
        print(elem.text)
```

-1

EDIT:Figured it out using BeautifulSoup. Posting the code:

```
content = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser') 
for tag in soup.find_all('a',{"class":"gsc_g_a"}):
    print (tag.text)
```

Comment: You should provide some Python code of yours

Comment: What did you try and what was not working ?

Comment: can you share a link to the web page?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `driver.find_element_by_class_name("gsc_g_al").text`?

Comment: returning an empty string. i will add the websote to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
linkTexts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='gsc_a_c']/a")
for e in linkTexts:
    e.text
```